# What client supports FTP from one server to another?

Tags: ftp

I usually use WS_FTP (Windows) to transfer files from one server to another (without having to first transfer them to my machine) but I don't have it here and would prefer to use a free tool.  Doesn't look like it's possible in FileZilla.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

What you are referring to is commonly known as "[FXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_eXchange_Protocol)" (*File eXchange Protocol* [sic], even though it's not a protocol, just a feature of FTP), and I was under the impression that most modern FTP servers disallowed it as a security feature, thus rendering support for it in FTP clients somewhat lacking as of late.

**Edit:**

See [ProFTPD and FXP](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/FXP.html) and [CERT® Advisory CA-1997-27 FTP Bounce](http://www.cert.org/advisories/CA-1997-27.html) for more information about FXP and why it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 2):

A free solution is [BitKinex](http://www.bitkinex.com/), which is now freeware and development has stopped since march 22, 2009:

> BitKinex integrates the fuctionality
>   of an innovative FTP, SFTP and WebDAV
>   client for Windows. In addition to
>   features found in other popular FTP
>   programs (like support for the
>   SSL/SSH, multipart and multithreaded
>   transfers, remote edit or **FXP**) our FTP
>   client introduces several unique
>   approaches and solutions.

Note: I've never used this FTP client and cannot vouch for it, but it's the only free solution I found.  Commercial products include SmartFTP, FTPRush, CrossFTP, FlashFXP.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[SmartFTP supports FXP](http://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/what-is-fxp-f14.html), but it's not free.

You can download a fully-featured trial version from their site.

Comment: Only if the server supports it, and the vast majority of FTP servers do not (disabled).

Answer (score 0):

Are both servers you transferring files between windows or are they linux boxes? On linux assuming you have shell access just use wget on windows servers install/use your favorite ftp client.

I see that some one changed the question so I may be missing something that was originally here.

Answer (score -1):

I'm quite sure there is no desktop client solution for this as it is not possible to do with the FTP protocol. I have used a PHP script and PHP's FTP functions to recursively and directly copy from one server to another where I had no shell access, however the successful completion of such an operation depends on many server settings like the maximum execution time for PHP.